Are there logics where disjunction idempotence does not hold?
Disjunction idempotence is the following theorem: $(P \vee P) \leftrightarrow P$. I wonder, are there logics that have been defined and studied in the literature where the right to left side of the biconditional holds, but the left to right side of the biconditional does not hold?

There are some logics where disjunction elimination does not hold, but I do not know of any studied logic where the idempotence case of disjunction elimination does not hold. The reason, I think, has a lot to do with the following.
For a reasonably behaving logic with $\lor$ and $\rightarrow$, the following should hold (presented in syntax of sequent calculi):

$p\Rightarrow p$ is provable
$p\Rightarrow q$ is provable iff $\Rightarrow p\rightarrow q$ is provable (law of residuation)
$p\lor q$ is definable as $(p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow q$
the cut rule

If these four things hold in some sequent calculi, then the idempotence of disjunction is provable as follows:

Assume $\Rightarrow p\lor p$.
$\Rightarrow (p\rightarrow p)\rightarrow p$ (rewriting $\lor$ in (1) into an implicational form)
$(p\rightarrow p)\Rightarrow p$ (use the law of residuation on (2))
$\Rightarrow (p\rightarrow p)$ (from $p\Rightarrow p$ by residuation)
$\Rightarrow p$ (the cut rule on (3) and (4))

So in a logic where idempotence of $\lor$ fails some of the above would have to be dropped. Now this is where my knowledge stops. I know that there are some arguments why e.g. the law of residuation is sort of a minimal condition that we should demand of $\rightarrow$. I imagine that if you drop any of the stuff above you will get pretty obscure logic, where $\lor$ and $\rightarrow$ (or at least one of them) will remain more or less only as symbols.
(The claim that the cut rule should not be dropped may be a bit confusing, since we encounter some sequent calculi without the cut rule. But that is usually only if also the cut-elimination theorem holds in such calculi, so the cut rule is derivable through other rules, and can therefore be dropped.)
